# Can't SSH in to remote server due to bad config

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I wrote a bad SSH config on a remote server while setting up Git and now I cannot access the server. Here is the error:

```
/users/<user>/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: AddKeysToAgent
/users/<user>/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: IgnoreUnknown
/users/<user>/.ssh/config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
```

I have tried to see if I can overwrite the config using rsync or something but I have been unsuccessful so far.
Is there any way to rescue this?

Answer (score 4):

> any way to rescue this?

Yes.
Ignore that local config file with

```
$ ssh -F none someserver
```

Or use a text editor to repair the config file.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question correctly the problem is on a remote server so the -F option won't help.   You'll need a non-ssh way of getting to it.  If it's a virtual server running under vmware for example,  vmware can open a console to provide access to fix the configuration.